# Point arrow to location (geolocation)

Tags: javascript, jquery, geolocation, compass-geolocation

i want to make a sort of compass on a mobile website.
This is what I have:

[image]

This is what i want:
[image]

I save my current location in the localstorage. Then for example 1km further I check my location and check the distance between the two points.

Now I want an arrow from the current location to the location in the localstorage.
The degrees from the phone I check with the javascript library "compass.js".

But now, how can I make the arrow to the location?

Comment: So you have an angle already, and just want to display an arrow with that angle?

Comment: i don't have an arrow yet. It's just an image. I want to make an arrow and point it in the direction of the location.

Comment: Can you help me how you calculate the angel. Share the js code that you use for calculating angle between two points

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as though you're trying to draw an image (an arrow) at a given rotation. Well, if we assume a modern browser (not a bad assumption for phones these days), that's quite easy. Just have an `img` on your page and apply a CSS transform on it.

See this site for more info on rotations in CSS: http://www.cssrotate.com/ (wow, somebody made an entire site for that…)

Now you also want to apply the rotation via JavaScript, so you'll need to change the CSS attribute dynamically. Since it's still quite new and has vendor prefixes, that's a little tricky, but not too hard. This site has a nice way to cope with it: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/setcss3properties.shtml

Putting it together, you could have this:

```
<img id="myarrow" src="myarrow.png" />
(blah)
<script>
// from http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/setcss3properties.shtml
function getsupportedprop(proparray){
    var root=document.documentElement;
    for (var i=0; i<proparray.length; i++){
        if (proparray[i] in root.style){
            return proparray[i];
        }
    }
    return false;
}
var cssTransform;
function setArrowRotation(x){
    if(cssTransform===undefined){
        cssTransform=getsupportedprop(['transform','webkitTransform','MozTransform','OTransform','msTransform']);
    }
    if(cssTransform){
        document.getElementById('myarrow').style[cssTransform]='rotate('+x+'deg)';
    }
}
</script>
```

Now just call `setArrowRotation` whenever you need to redirect the arrow.

Here's a fiddle which continuously rotates the arrow: http://jsfiddle.net/y2sxE/

Comment: And how can I rotate this into the direction of the location I saved earlier?

Comment: You can call `setArrowRotation` with any value you like. Just load your value and call that function.

Comment: If you have 2 locations, you can use `atan2` to get an angle, then subtract the angle from the one given by Compass.js. You'll want to put all this in an interval like in my fiddle so that it updates as the device is rotated. Also you might need to play with adding 0/90/180/270 to make the arrow image line-up properly (which one of those you'll need depends on the image and on how Compass.js works, so it's easier to just try them)